# detect whether wearable app is installing / installed

Tags: android, wear-os

That whole wearable-app-installation-thing is a black box to me. I package my wearable app like I was told on http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html and after installing the mobile app I have to wait some minutes until the wearable tells me that installation was successful. This is no good user experience. I'd like make that process more transparent to the user. Something like discovering whether the wearable app was installed already, when installation starts and when it ends.

Are there some broadcasts I can react to?

Can I add some installation listeners?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there aren't any callbacks/intents.

What you can do, is keep sending (with some back off) messages (using MessageApi) to the wearable. In your wearable application set up a WearableListenerService. When your wearable app is installed, it will pick up one of these messages and can acknowledge the installation (by posting a DataItem). Then you can show in your UI on the phone, that the wearable application is installed.